# Using parameter to control Rails validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, controller, dry

I have an `Event` model with a `finish_time` field and a form checkbox called `whenever`. When `whenever` is checked I want to set `finish_time` to `nil` regardless of its value in parameters, when `whenever` is not checked I want to make sure that `finish_time` is a valid date before I save it in the database.

---

Currently I am achieving this using a `whenever` attr_accessor on Event:

```
params[:event][:finish_time] = nil if whenever = params[:event].delete(:whenever)
@event = Event.new(params[:event])
@event.whenever = whenever
```

And using conditional validations to check for `finish_time` if `whenever` is `false`

```
validates_presence_of :finish_time, :unless => @whenever
```

---

I am not happy with the duplication this creates. The only way that `finish_time` can be `nil` is if `whenever` is `true`, and if you change one you often have to change the other. If the `Event` is updated with a new `finish_time` then `whenever` will have to be changed to `false` as well.

Ideally I would like to move the validation to my controller. That way when doing direct model access `whenever` can be easily indicated by setting `finish_time` to `null`, but users posting to /events will get yelled at if they haven't indicated a choice. However I can't figure out a way to conditionally add or remove validations to `Event` from the controller or even if this is the best approach.

What is the best way to remove this duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to solve problem via validation, you might try to address it in "a Ruby way".

In addition to validation, you might want to hook into mutators of `finish_time` and `whenever` methods.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Validate presence
  validates_presence_of :finish_time, :unless => @whenever

  def whenever=(yes)
    write_attribute(:whenever, yes)
    write_attribute(:finish_time, nil) if yes?
  end
  def finish_time=(time)
    write_attribute(:whenever, false)
    write_attribute(:finish_time, time)
  end
end
```

Then you can just try (however, I'm not sure whether it works):

```
@event = Event.new(params[:event])
```

**Edit:** However, this will make the resultant fields *depend on the order assignemnts happen*, so the results for the same parameter set may differ if the order of assignments changes.  That's unlikely what you want.  So you must tune your opertators the way you want.

And you also should understand that you won't be able to make your code DRY unless you make your requirements DRY.

**Edit #2:**  I think you should consider dropping the requirement for `finish_time` to be `nil` if `whenever` is set to true.  You can then modify accessors in the same way as described above.

Comment: Good point about keeping my requirements DRY. Maybe there is some Date value other than null that could indicate "don't care" instead of empty? I think the problem comes from making one value mean two things. I can't think of any way that doesn't resort to magic numbers.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!